# Assistance needed scraping a site with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape the NBA player names and projected fantasy score (not single stat DFS) using selenium. I've gotten as far as using selenium to automate clicking NBA, and selecting the fantasy score tab.

From there, I see the players in a grid where I will like to scrape the points and names for each player. I have attempted to loop through the grid but I don't think I'm doing it right

Can someone please take a look at my code and point me in the right direction ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import pandas as pd

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://app.prizepicks.com/")

popup = driver.find_element_by_class_name("close").click()
NBA = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='name'][normalize-space()='NBA']").click()
fantasyScore = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='segment-selector-button']").click()

projections = driver.find_element_by_class_name('projections')

nbaPlayers = []

for projection in projections:
    
    names = projection.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="projections"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]').text
    points= projection.fine_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="projections"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/text()').text
    print(names, points)
    
    players = {
        'Name': names,
        'FantasyPoints':points,
        }
    
    nbaPlayers.append(players)

df = pd.DataFrame(nbaPlayers)
print(df)

driver.quit()
```

Edit: 6.12.21 5:22 PM CST
This was the first part of my code that was fixed by C. Peck (Thanks!)
The next part of the code was also unsuccessful.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#sample data
pp = {'Player Name':['Donovan Mitchell', 'Kawhi Leonard', 'Rudy Gobert', 'Paul George','Reggie Jackson', 'Jordan Clarkson'],
      'Fantasy Score': [46.0, 50.0, 40.0, 44.0, 25.0, 26.5]}

#Creating a dataframe from dictionary
dfNBA = pd.DataFrame(pp)

#Scraping ESPN
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.espn.com/")

#Clicking the search button
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='global-search-trigger']").click() 

#sending data to the search button
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search Sports, Teams or Players...']").send_keys(dfNBA.iloc[0,:].values[0])
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search_results__details")))
playerPage = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".search_results__details").click()

#Scraping data from last 10 games
points = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='fittPageContainer']/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[1]/section/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[13]")
rebs = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='fittPageContainer'']/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[1]/section/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]")                                    
asts = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='fittPageContainer']/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[1]/section/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]")
blks = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='fittPageContainer']/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[1]/section/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[9]")
stls = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='fittPageContainer']/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[1]/section/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[10]")
tnvrs = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='fittPageContainer']/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[1]/section/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[12]")

projectedPoints = points+(rebs*1.2)+(asts*1.5)+(blks*3)+(stls*3)-(tnvrs*1)
print(projectedPoints)


#my final table should look like:
#Index   Name           FantasyPoints  ESPN L10 Avg
#0     Donovan Mitchell      46           27.8
```

The goal of this project is to first scrape PrizePicks and get the NBA players names & fantasy score points, then store the scraped data into a dataframe using the stored dataframe data, I attempted to iterate through each row, then take the players names and plug it into the ESPN search box. This should bring up the players page. On the players page, I attempted to scrape the points, rebs, assts, steals, blks, turnovers etc and then add them up using the formula in the projectedPoints variable

So ultimately, I will be able to calculate the projected points for each player and compared those points to the fantasy score points scraped from Prize Picks. Using this comparison, I will make my decision if the player will be OVER or UNDER the fantasy score points

Comment: I can see there elements located by class name `projections`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to your code, and now I think it gives the output you want.

Changes I made:

1. When you are using `.click()`, it is useless to define a variable as `element.click()`, so I got rid of those.
2. You want to use `find_elements` instead of `find_element` to get an array of WebElements to iterate through.
3. The xpaths for `names` and `points` weren't quite right, so I fixed them.
4. I needed to induce `WebDriverWait` in order for the `projection` elements to exist when you look for them. This requires the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

So your final code could be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://app.prizepicks.com/")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("close").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='name'][normalize-space()='NBA']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='segment-selector-button']").click()
projections = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
 EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".projection")))

nbaPlayers = []

for projection in projections:

    names = projection.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="name"]').text
    points= projection.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="presale-score"]').get_attribute('innerHTML')
    print(names, points)

    players = {
        'Name': names,
        'FantasyPoints':points,
        }

    nbaPlayers.append(players)

df = pd.DataFrame(nbaPlayers)
print(df)

driver.quit()
```

Output is:

```
Donovan Mitchell 46.0
Kawhi Leonard 50.0
Rudy Gobert 40.0
Paul George 44.0
Mike Conley 29.5
Reggie Jackson 25.0
Jordan Clarkson 25.0
Marcus Morris 23.0
Bojan Bogdanovic 25.0
Ivica Zubac 16.0
Royce O'Neale 22.0
Nicolas Batum 19.0
Joe Ingles 22.0
Patrick Beverley 10.0
                Name FantasyPoints
0   Donovan Mitchell          46.0
1      Kawhi Leonard          50.0
2        Rudy Gobert          40.0
3        Paul George          44.0
4        Mike Conley          29.5
5     Reggie Jackson          25.0
6    Jordan Clarkson          25.0
7      Marcus Morris          23.0
8   Bojan Bogdanovic          25.0
9        Ivica Zubac          16.0
10     Royce O'Neale          22.0
11     Nicolas Batum          19.0
12        Joe Ingles          22.0
13  Patrick Beverley          10.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's why I love this community.
I spent a few hours trying to figure it out on my own and was getting frustrated

Answer (score 3):

You could do this more easily without `Selenium` since the data is dynamically loaded from an api:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

params = (
    ('league_id', '7'),
    ('per_page', '250'),
    ('projection_type_id', '1'),
    ('single_stat', 'true'),
)

session = requests.Session() 
response = session.get('https://api.prizepicks.com/projections', data=params)

df1 = pd.json_normalize(response.json()['included'])
df1 = df1[df1['type'] == 'new_player']

df2 = pd.json_normalize(response.json()['data'])

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(df1['attributes.name'], df2['attributes.line_score']), columns=['name', 'points'])
```

Output:

|  | name | points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Donovan Mitchell | 46 |
| 1 | Kawhi Leonard | 50 |
| 2 | Rudy Gobert | 40 |
| 3 | Paul George | 44 |
| 4 | Mike Conley | 29.5 |

Comment: Not familiar with this method. But thanks!

It is simple, short and works

Comment: ...and much more efficient and robust. Always go with the api feed if available.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see there elements matching `projections` class name, but if they should be there you should use `find_elements` instead of `find_element`.
I guess your code should be like this to achieve players names and scores:

```
nbaPlayers = []

players = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='player']")
for player in players:
    name = player.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class='name']').text
    points = player.find_element_by_xpath('./../..//div[@class='presale-score']').text
    print(names, points)
    data = {
        'Name': name,
        'FantasyPoints':points,
        }
    
    nbaPlayers.append(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

See you are using

```
projections = driver.find_element_by_class_name('projections')
```

and looping through like this :

```
for projection in projections:
```

This will return a sing web element. But your requirement demands a list of players name right ?

so use `find_elements` instead :

```
names = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.player div.name")
for player_name in names:
    print(player_name.text)
```

Same you can replicate for ratings, `CSS_SELECTOR` would be `div.score div`